# Couldn't save "long" in Shared Preference

Tags: java, android, preference

I am saving "long" in Sharedpreferences as below :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("STARTTIME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putLong("startTime", startTime);
    editor.commit();
```

and Retreiving "long" from Sharedpreference as below :

```
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("STARTTIME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long getstartTime = preferences.getLong(startTime, 0);
```

But I am getting value "0" while retreiving.....Any guess where am i making mistake ?

Comment: you missed a pair of "": preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
long getstartTime = preferences.getLong(startTime, 0);
```

should be

```
long getstartTime = preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);
```

Android interpreted the `startTime` as a resource id, and because it didn't find it, you get the default value, that you passed in, as returnvalue.

Comment: Aah...Yes, thanks...I was wondering too...I didn't get compile error, earlier I was trying the same but then it would give error to change "getLong" to "getString" which was strange...

Comment: At first I also expected oyu to get a compile error, but then I remembered that you can load Strings by resource ids so I put the explanation. :) You should mark an answer as accepted in order for other users also to identify solutions similar problems.

Comment: Thanks Devolus, can u tell me where to accept. I never tried it. I am sure that will be really helpful for other developers

Comment: On the left of the answer are small up and down arrows. here you can vote if an answer or a question was good or not. If you get an answer to your own question you also see a chechmark below these arrows. Here you can accept an answer. You should read these links as they will answer those questions in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering and http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation

Comment: Thanks Devolus...I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the same key to the `getLong()` method i.e. literal **"startTime"** .

```
long getstartTime = preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);
```